# How to create an android app from a python-flask web app created on the desktop?

Tags: android, python-3.x, flask

I've created a simple app, rather a basic "HelloWorld" app, just for sake testing the web app and for converting it into an Android app. This is the following code:

```
    from flask import Flask 

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World'

    if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run()
```

Comment: You can use flask as the application backend. Flask doesn't have anything with python mobile app development.

Answer (score 9):

The quickstart for the specific kivy project to use can be found at:

https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

Look at **"Build a WebView application"**

`p4a apk --private $HOME/code/myapp --package=org.example.myapp --name "My WebView Application" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=webview --requirements=flask --port=5000`